# Why I can't push -1 to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, push, counting

```
function map(arr) {
  let m = new Map();
  arr.forEach((num) => {
    m.set(`${num}`, m.get(`${num}`) == undefined ? 1 : m.get(`${num}`) + 1);
  });

  let result = [];

  m.forEach((cnt, num) => (cnt > 1 ? result.push(+cnt) : ""));

  if (result == []) {
    result.push(-1);
  }

  console.log(result);
}

map([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]); // [ 4, 2 ]
map([3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5]); // [ 3, 2, 3 ]
map([3, 5, 7, 9, 1]); // []
```

I want to [-1] if there isn't duplicated numbers.
But -1 is not push to result array. Why?
I want to know better code to count duplicated numbers to front to back.

`result == [] ? result.push(-1) : "";`
Or tried unshift() instead using push() method.
But it's same output.

Comment: because `[] !== []` ... check for `!result.length` instead

Comment: ^ This is the answer. In Javascript, the `==` operator when applied to objects checks whether the objects are *the exact same object*, and not whether they are equivalent. You can write your own `.equals()` function to compare objects but since you appear to be simply checking if the array is empty, `.length == 0` will suffice as well (or the shorter `!result.length` as suggested above).

Comment: I would also suggest familiarizing yourself with the devtools of your browser/IDE of choice. In this case, you could insert a breakpoint on your if statement and see that the condition is never satisfied and you never enter the block. Therefore the problem is not the `result.push(-1)` at all, but rather the condition of the if statement.

Comment: That's very helpful suggestion! I lacked of understanding about javascript objects and debugging. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition check is wrong. The condition **`result == []`** will evaluate to false, even if result is an empty array. To compare the contents of arrays, you should use other methods such as **`result.length === 0`**.

Arrays are reference types, and when comparing them with the equality operator, JavaScript checks if the references to the arrays are the same, rather than comparing their contents.

Replace your if condition with code below and it should work.

```js
if (result.length === 0) {
    result.push(-1);
  }
```

Read more about `primitive` and `reference` types in javascript [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch04s04.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when you check "result" *array length* instead of comparing result with empty array:

```
  if (result.length == 0) {
    result.push(-1);
  }
```

It means that Javascript somehow cannot lay identity between empty array and [] It possibly considers [] as being another different instance...

Answer (score 1):

As @JaromandaX has explained in the comments you would have to test for an empty array another way.

Change:

```
result == []
```

To:

```
!result.length
```

As in the live demo below:

```js
function map(arr) {
  let m = new Map();
  arr.forEach((num) => {
    m.set(`${num}`, m.get(`${num}`) == undefined ? 1 : m.get(`${num}`) + 1);
  });

  let result = [];

  m.forEach((cnt, num) => (cnt > 1 ? result.push(+cnt) : ""));

  if (!result.length) {
    result.push(-1);
  }

  console.log(result);
}

map([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]); // [ 4, 2 ]
map([3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5]); // [ 3, 2, 3 ]
map([3, 5, 7, 9, 1]); // [ -1 ]
```

**Or ...**

Alternatively, you could replace the `if` statement with:

```
result.length || result.push(-1);
```

```js
function map(arr) {
  let m = new Map();
  arr.forEach((num) => {
    m.set(`${num}`, m.get(`${num}`) == undefined ? 1 : m.get(`${num}`) + 1);
  });

  let result = [];

  m.forEach((cnt, num) => (cnt > 1 ? result.push(+cnt) : ""));

  result.length || result.push(-1);

  console.log(result);
}

map([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]); // [ 4, 2 ]
map([3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5]); // [ 3, 2, 3 ]
map([3, 5, 7, 9, 1]); // [ -1 ]
```